# Count the same element in different lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to know how you can count the number of times the same element appears in different lists in Python. The number of lists is not determined

For example:

```
[house,table,house]
[desk,computer,table]
```

would return a dictionary with

```
{house:[2,0], table:[1,1], desk:[0,1]}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Are those lists supposed to contain strings? Where do they come from?

Comment: Supposing your input are strings, you can make use of `Counter` from `collections`. Look it up

Answer (score 1):

An easy way, if you don't want to import other tools, would be to use a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) to keep count.

```
list_1 = ['house','table','house']
list_2 = ['desk','computer','table'] 

# instantiate a dict that will contain the number of appearances in each list, as a list
appearances = {}

# loop through the first list
for item in list_1:
    # If the item hasn't appeared yet, it will set the item's name as the key and [1, 0] as the value
    # appearances[item] is how we're going to set the key name in appearances
    # appearances.get(item, 0)[0] makes it so that if item is not a key in appearances, it sets the initial value at index 0 to [0, 0]. 
    #   Otherwise, it sets it to +1 of it's current value
    # We set appearances[item] to a list so that we can keep track of appearances in both lists
    # For list_1's first item, appearances would then be equal to: appearances = {'house': [1, 0]}
    appearances[item] = [appearances.get(item, [0, 0])[0] + 1, 0]

# Do the same for the second list, but use index of 1, instead of 0
for item in list_2:
    # We use appearances.get() twice in case we haven't seen the item yet in either list
    appearances[item] = [appearances.get(item, [0, 0])[0], appearances.get(item, [0, 0])[1] + 1]

# Print the result
print(appearances)
```

Comment: How will your algorithm adapt to the change in the number of lists??

Comment: @mad_ It doesn't and I was aware of that when writing my response. It seemed like a beginner question, so I stuck with a beginner answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looked interesting so I gave it a try. It will work with an arbitrary number of lists

```
a= [['house','table','house'],['desk','computer','table']]
from itertools import chain
d={}
for key in set(chain(*a)): #chain to get all the unique keys possible
    d.setdefault(key,[]) # set default value of every key as an empty list

for lis in a:           # Iterate over the list of lists

    for j in set(lis):  #convert the list to set as we do not want to count the items multiple times
        d[j].append(lis.count(j)) #append the count to the list associated with the key

    for key in set(d.keys())-set(lis): #keys which are present in power set but not in subset means item is not present
        d[key].append(0)    #append count as 0

print(d)
```

Voila you should get output like below

```
{'house': [2, 0], 'computer': [0, 1], 'table': [1, 1], 'desk': [0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that accepts an arbitrary number of lists, which you will traverse and for each element that exists, you will count the number of occurences for each list:

```
list1 = ['house','table','house']
list2 = ['desk','computer','table']

def countElements(*lists):
    elements = set([elem for l in lists for elem in l])
    return dict((element,[l.count(element) for l in lists]) for element in elements)

print(countElements(list1,list2))
```

Result:

```
{'table': [1, 1], 'computer': [0, 1], 'house': [2, 0], 'desk': [0, 1]}
```

Alternatively you could store all those lists in another list and traverse them again with the same way:

```
list1 = ['house','table','house']
list2 = ['desk','computer','table']

def countElements(lists):
    elements = set([elem for l in lists for elem in l])
    return dict((element,[l.count(element) for l in lists]) for element in elements)

print(countElements([list1,list2]))
```

Notice the difference in function signature and in function call (the argument is a list of lists).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative more verbose but easy to follow.

First place the lists in a containing sueperlist:

```
superlist = [l1, l2]
```

Then initialise a dictionary (`word_count`) with the required keys (each word appearing in the lists):

```
word_count={}
for lst in superlist:
  for w in set(lst):
    word_count.setdefault(w, list())
```

Finally, iterate over the word_count picking up the count of the encountered words:

```
for word in word_count.keys():
  for lst in superlist:
    word_count[word].append(lst.count(word))
```

Now `word_count` contains:

```
#=> {'house': [2, 0], 'table': [1, 1], 'desk': [0, 1], 'computer': [0, 1]}
```

---

**All in a method for any number of list:**

```
def count_words(*superlist):
  word_count={}
  for lst in superlist:
    for w in set(lst):
      word_count.setdefault(w, list())
  for word in word_count.keys():
    for lst in superlist:
      word_count[word].append(lst.count(word))
  return word_count

print(count_words(l1, l2))
#=> {'table': [1, 1], 'house': [2, 0], 'desk': [0, 1], 'computer': [0, 1]}
```